# Can't Customize Radio Button

Tags: react-native, native-base, customizing

trying to customize radio button. It works for background or buttonsize, but not working for icon size, color and positioning.

what could be wrong?

here's my code and my result.

Radio.js

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";

import variable from "./../variables/platform";

export default (variables = variable) => {
  const radioTheme = {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    lineHeight: 20,
    ".selected": {
      color: '#7ED321',
      "NativeBase.IconNB": {
        color: '#7ED321',
        lineHeight: '20',
        fontSize: '20'
      }
    },
    "NativeBase.IconNB": {
      color: '#7ED321',
      lineHeight: '20',
      fontSize: '20'
    }
  };

  return radioTheme;
};
```

And here's the button positioning, size and color. (color should be green as hex)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the radio button color and radio button size from the native-base-theme/variables/*.js

For size just make appropriate changes in the size based on your platform

```
radioBtnSize: platform === "ios" ? 25 : 23,
```

For color return your desired color

```
get radioColor() {
  return "blue";
},
```